# ListFragment error: Content view not yet created

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, android-listfragment

i have this message error in my listFragment, i've tried some solutions proposed in other topics about the same issue but it still doesn't work. I don't get the error at the first time but after some navigation between the fragments..
Here is the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
        at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:328)
        at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:222)
        at com.rajaapp.ui.InboxFragment$2$1.done(InboxFragment.java:136)
        at com.rajaapp.ui.InboxFragment$2$1.done(InboxFragment.java:121)
        at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:107)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the fragment code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inbox, container, false);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setItems(R.array.camera_choices,mDialogListener);
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(mOnRefreshListener);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(
            R.color.swipeRefresh1,
            R.color.swipeRefresh2,
            R.color.swipeRefresh3,
            R.color.swipeRefresh4
    );

    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mprogressBar = (ProgressBar) getView().findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    fab.attachToListView(getListView());
    retrieveMessages();
}

private void retrieveMessages() {
    mAbonnementsRelation = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getRelation(ParseConstants.KEY_ABONNEMENTS_RELATION);
    mAbonnementsRelation.getQuery().findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseUser> abonnes, ParseException e) {
            if(e==null){
                int i = 0;
                for (ParseUser abonne : abonnes) {
                    AbonnesIds.add(abonne.getObjectId());
                    i++;
                }
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(ParseConstants.CLASS_MESSAGES);
                query.whereContainedIn(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_ID, AbonnesIds);
                query.addDescendingOrder(ParseConstants.KEY_CREATED_AT);
                if (!mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                    mprogressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> messages, ParseException e) {
                        mprogressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        if (mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        }
                        if (e == null) {
                            mMessages = messages;
                            String[] usernames = new String[mMessages.size()];
                            int i = 0;
                            for (ParseObject message : mMessages) {
                                usernames[i] = message.getString(ParseConstants.KEY_SENDER_NAME);
                                i++;
                            }
                            if (getListView().getAdapter() == null) {
                                MessageAdapter adapter = new MessageAdapter(getListView().getContext()
                                        , mMessages);
                                setListAdapter(adapter);
                            } else {
                                ((MessageAdapter) getListView().getAdapter()).refill(mMessages);
                                ((MessageAdapter) getListView().getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

}
```

The error occurs in this line:

```
if (getListView().getAdapter() == null) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inbox, container, false);
```

Replace container to null . and move all code onActivityCreated to onCreateView

Comment: still having the same error at if (getListView().getAdapter() == null)  :/

Comment: I can't, i'm using a fragmentPagerAdapter, there a 3others fragments actually